# How to rotate 3d point?

Tags: javascript, arrays, 3d, render, vertex

I'm currently developing a 3d renderer in js.

I'd like to render cubes - and that is working pretty well - but what I'd like to do is something like a rotation of each cube.

So I got some vertex of a cube and I want to rotate the x/y/z (pitch, roll, yaw) of every cube around itself.

This is the 3d rotation function:

```
let rotate3d = (points = [0,0,0], pitch = 0, roll = 0, yaw = 0) => {
    let cosa = Math.cos(yaw),
        sina = Math.sin(yaw);
    let cosb = Math.cos(pitch),
        sinb = Math.sin(pitch);
    let cosc = Math.cos(roll),
        sinc = Math.sin(roll);
    let Axx = cosa*cosb,
        Axy = cosa*sinb*sinc - sina*cosc,
        Axz = cosa*sinb*cosc + sina*sinc;
    let Ayx = sina*cosb,
        Ayy = sina*sinb*sinc + cosa*cosc,
        Ayz = sina*sinb*cosc - cosa*sinc;
    let Azx = -sinb,
        Azy = cosb*sinc,
        Azz = cosb*cosc;
    let px = points[0];
    let py = points[1];
    let pz = points[2];
    points[0] = Axx*px + Axy*py + Axz*pz;
    points[1] = Ayx*px + Ayy*py + Ayz*pz;
    points[2] = Azx*px + Azy*py + Azz*pz;
    return points;
  }
```

and this is a snippet from my renderer routine:

```js
for (let vert of cube.vertex) {
  let x = vert[0] - camera.position[0],
      y = vert[1] - camera.position[1],
      z = vert[2] - camera.position[2];

  if (cube.rotation) {
    cube.rotation += Math.PI * 0.02;
    let p = rotate(vert.slice(0), cube.r, 0, 0)
    x = p[0] - camera.position[0]
    y = p[1] - camera.position[1]
    z = p[2] - camera.position[2]
  }
  
  # ... draw polygons (cube) by converting 3d coordinates to 2d coordinates.
}
```

---

[See gif 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjtT6.gif)

**So**: If the cube is spawned at [0, -1, 0] the program rotates this cube around the y-axis (clockwise). But changing the spawn to [1, -1, 0] lets the cube rotate around the same point (origin) but with space 1. I'd like to rotate the cube on it's spawn!

[See gif 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9p1r7.gif)

**Edit**: This is the spawning cube routine:

```
spawn(p) {
    this.position = p;
    const vertex = [[-1,-1,-1], [1,-1,-1], [1,1,-1], [-1,1,-1], [-1,-1,1], [1,-1,1], [1,1,1], [-1,1,1]];
    this.vertex = []
    for (let vert of vertex) {
      let position = []
      for (let i=0; i<vert.length; i++) position.push(vert[i]/2 + this.position[i])
      this.vertex.push(position)
    }
}
```

---

So my question: How to edit the rotate function to add a origin point where I'd like to rotate the cube around?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to specify the point to rotate around is:

1. Translate (move) your object so that the rotation point is at origin (0,0,0)
2. Rotate the required amount
3. Do an opposite translation to the one in step 1.

In (pseudo)code:

```
var translationVector = originPoint.minus(rotationPoint);
myObject.translate(translationVector);
myObject.rotate(eulerX, eulerY, eulerZ);
myObject.translate(-translationVector);
```